# When trying to extract even values I keep getting typeError: 'int' object is not iterable whn tryoing

Tags: python

New to this here. Trying to learn Python a bit for automating some stuff. I was doing this exercise to find even numbers in a string but keep getting: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Here is the code:

```
def extract_odd_digits(some_string):
    """return list of all odd digits in string"""
    # empty list of found digits
    digits = []
    # check for each character if it is odd
    
    for char in(some_string):
        some_string=list(some_string)
        if char in ["0","2","4","6","8"]:
            list.append(digits, char)
        return digits
    
extract_even_digits (12345654321)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `some_string` is an int, not a string. If it is supposed to be a string, then you mean `'12345654321'`.

Comment: Your check if it is odd or not, is not general. Make it like this `if (int(char) % 2) != 0:` Then add it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the numbers to a string:

```
def extract_odd_digits(some_string):
    """return list of all odd digits in string"""
    # empty list of found digits
    digits = []
    # check for each character if it is odd
    
    for char in(some_string):
        some_string=list(some_string)
        if char in ["0","2","4","6","8"]:
            list.append(digits, char)
        return digits
    
extract_even_digits ("12345654321")
```

Answer (score 0):

the number you are passing into the function is of datatype `int` while your function tries to iterate over that input as the datatype `int` cannot be iterated over. you need to convert your input into string before iterating over it if your input will be 12345654321. consider creating a list of integers if possible which can be iterated over. I would do it as follows:

```
def extract_odd_digits(some_list):
    """return list of all odd digits in string"""
    assert type(some_list) == list # make sure your input is list and can be iterated over 
    return [i for i in some_list if i%2!=0] # return a list of only odd integers
```

if you cannot pass a list then I would do something like this

```
def extract_odd_digits(some_string):
    """return list of all odd digits in string"""
    # empty list of found digits
    odd_digits = []
    # convert digits into string as you cannot iterate over a integer
    digits = [i for i in str(some_string)]
    # loop over your digits to find if each string
    for i in digits:
        try:
            integer = int(i)
            if integer%2!=0:
                odd_digits.append(int(i))
        except:
            pass
    return odd_digits

extract_odd_digits(123123143141421)
[1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3]
```